# How to add a "Skip to main content" link that only shows to screen readers, using Tailwind CSS?

Tags: hyperlink, accessibility, tailwind-css

The video below describes adding a "Skip to main content" link at the top of a web page and making it visible only by users with screen readers, using plain CSS.

*The idea is to improve accessibility by allowing screen readers a way to bypass all the navigation, etc. and get to the main content*

How can this be done with Tailwind CSS?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VUR0I5mqq7I

Comment: As Mark said, you can use the `.sr-only` class, however it's considered best-practice to make them visible on focus. You may need to write some custom CSS to make that work. https://webaim.org/techniques/skipnav/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tailwind CSS let you designate elements as on visible to screen readers via "sr-only"

Code example (just inside the  tag):

`<a href="#main-content" class="text-center bg-black text-white underline text-2xl sr-only focus:not-sr-only">Skip to main content</a>`

And then add `<main id="main-content">` where the main content begins on that page.

And lastly, add the closing `</main>` tag right after the page's main content ends.

Link to TailwindCSS's [screen reader only documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/screen-readers#screen-reader-only-elements)

Comment: You should also add `focus:not-sr-only` to make the link visible on tab. Accessibility is not only about screen readers, and keyboard users in general profit from these skip links.